# start new Android Activity is so slow

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to open a new Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(homeScreen.this, EmployeeService.class);         
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt(Constants.SERVICE_DETAIL_L1_ID_MSG, ServiceIndex.SRV_L1_EMPLOYMENT);
b.putInt(Constants.SERVICE_DETAIL_FOCUS_POS_MSG, 2);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

But it takes so long to make destination Activity (EmployeeService) become visible. From Logcat, I see:

```
05-14 23:43:31.727: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity fr.playsoft.happylille/.employee.EmployeeService: 7050 ms (total 7050 ms)
```

I cannot believe it take more than 7 seconds just to open a new Activity. I add a log in onCreate() but see it only take 5ms to finish onCreate.

Can anyone tell me how to find the root of this problem?

Comment: OK. I know why. Because in target Activity, I set tvDesc.setText(Html.fromHtml(desc)); with desc is the content of a long web page with HTML tag. Process HTML page with may not-supported tag make my Activity slowly display!

Comment: You could put the processing in a separate thread.

Comment: @Olafure: that's a really good idea. Now it works well.

Comment: @olafure can you give me an example. Lets say we have for loop, and we need to run it on onCreate. how can we do this in a different thread ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move the code `Html.fromHtml(desc);` to a thread to have it asynchronous. This thread can safely be started during the `onCreate()` of the newly opened `Activity`.

At the end of that thread, you can run `tvDesc.setText()` from the UI thread:

```
class ExampleThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         final Spanned spannedText = Html.fromHtml(desc);

         yourNewlyOpenedActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tvDesc.setText(spannedText);
                }
         });
    }
}
```

More generally, 7 seconds on a device maybe means 20 on another, so [beware the ANR](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html)!

(Edited further to [Boy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/969016/boy)'s comment below, the former version of this answer was no longer accurate/valid)

Comment: I don't believe you are allowed to do 'setText' on a non-UI thread

Comment: @Boy When I wrote this, I was on API level 8. It was working but I did not re-test since then (no need). So I can't guarantee this is still valid, did you give a try?

Comment: I didn't retest, because I was pretty sure. But I just did and will post a new answer, text would be too long here

Comment: @Boy Ah, so you re-tested! Thanks for the update boy, I corrected this answer.

Comment: @Boy Thanks! You helped the community (including myself) by finding that this answer needed updating. This deserves a +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

[Shlublu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6869287/969016) is incorrect, you are not allowed to do UI updates from non-UI threads!

It seems to work at first, but that is just luck, timing.

just a quick ugly test proves that it will go wrong at the 'right' timing. Here I set a text every 100 ms. Will crash in about 1 second:

```
      new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                someTextView.setText("bla");

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

It will throw this error: `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

I think you should execute the `Html.fromHtml(desc)` via an `AsyncTask` or [RxJava](http://blog.stablekernel.com/replace-asynctask-asynctaskloader-rx-observable-rxjava-android-patterns/)

Answer (score 0):

your open new activity code put in Thread . and run code may be less time to required open another activity..may be helpfully.