# How to populate activity when splash ends without delay?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am Loading all the data on splash Activity and when all calls return I want to populate another activity but keeping the splash activity until the main activity is populated.

I tried using AsyncTask but still not working, I have a delay when switching from the splash activity to the main activity.

I expect to go from splash activity to another Activity without Delay and the activity to be populated.

Comment: Share some code

Comment: why this question has be downvoted?

Comment: I did not downvote your question but "I tried using AsyncTask but still not working", is a very general question - there could be a lot of reasons for your problem but with your code attached stack overflow community can narrow it  down and help you

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions to your problem:

1. Disable animation when starting your `MainActivity` and try to minimize the consuming tasks in that activity.
2. Combine SplashScreen to your MainActivity as a `View`, after finishing loading all necessary tasks, just hide that `SplashScreen View`

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload the part of your code where you are calling the intent to the other activity before we can actually understand what is wrong. However, ensure you are not doing too much activity on the application main thread since this can make your UI unresponsive and make the app slow. See this for reference =>

https://medium.com/@yossisegev/understanding-activity-runonuithread-e102d388fe93

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads

[start new Android Activity is so slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003344/start-new-android-activity-is-so-slow)

You can also make your app call the new activity on a separate thread to ensure all the data it needs to pass to the other activity is received before navigating to the new activity and also ensure you are not doing too many resource consuming task in the onCreate method of the new activity you are calling

Comment: I am launching my app on the main activity than I am starting the splash activity inside the main activity and on ActivityResult I am populating all the data.